# HTML5 Audio Player using AngularJs through $http Service

Tags: angularjs, html, audio, html5-audio

**HTML View**

```
<audio ng-src="{{vm.videourlsce}}" autoplay preload="auto" controls="controls" autobuffer></audio>
```

Inside my controller get the data from remover server using $http service and update to player

```
var vm = this;
vm.videourlsce = '';
$http.get(SERVER.apiurl+"resources/get_resource/?id="+$stateParams.id)    
.success(function(response){                    
     vm.resources = response.resource;                                          
     vm.videourl = vm.resources.url;                                                                          

}).error(function(error){                    
    console.log("Resources error");
});
$scope.$watch('vm.videourl', function(newVal, oldVal){
   if (newVal !== undefined) {
       console.log("Old Val => "+oldVal);
       console.log("New Val => "+newVal);
       vm.videourlsce = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(newVal);  
   }
});
```

After getting service response, the audio URL bind to audio tag on src attribute and playing the audio. But the controls are not working. When I remove autoplay option from the audio tag, nothing will happen. Those controls are not working when clicking the play button.

When I hard-code this URL instead of getting from service it works fine. Does anyone help to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue with browser incorrectly handling the change of `audio` source. Try this workaround.

```
<div data-ng-if="vm.videourlsce">
    <audio ng-src="{{ ::vm.videourlsce }}" autoplay preload="auto" controls="controls" autobuffer></audio>
</div>
```

---

#### Update

After the OP has supplied the [codepen](http://codepen.io/aruljayaraj/pen/YpNrgb) it became clear the problem lies in ionic intercepting click and touch events. It is easily fixed by setting attribute `data-tap-disabled="true"` on a node.

```
<div data-ng-if="videourl" data-tap-disabled="true" class="item item-body no-padding">
    <audio autoplay preload="auto" controls="controls" autobuffer>
        <source src="{{ ::videourl }}" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
</div>
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLgzOx)

Comment: Audio is playing, but the controls(Play and pause) still not working in Firefox. At the same time, chrome seems good. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I've tried ogg format for firefox. That also won't help.

Comment: create a Fiddle complying with [MVCE standarts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your support. I've created codepen. I don't know why the controls(play/pause) not works on firefox. But this is my code.http://codepen.io/aruljayaraj/pen/YpNrgb

Comment: @Arul start with this step next time - it's much easier to help you when we have a working example. I've checked your codepen and found the problem, updating the answer.